# First key, value pair in dictionary getting overwritten by the next

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

I have a simple yet confounding problem. I have a nested list of data that needs organizing into a dictionary. When I enter the code:

```
>>>data = [['a', 1, 'b', 2], ['c', 3, 'd', 4], ['e', 5, 'f', 7]]
>>>dict1 = {}
>>>dict1[data[0][0]] = data[0][1]
>>>dict1
{'a': '1'}
```

I get {'a': '1'}, as you would expect. However, when I attempt to write my second (key, value) pair into my dictionary, the first entry is missing.

```
>>>dict1[data[0][2]] = data[0][3]
>>>dict1
{'b': '2'}
```

Where did the first entry go? It seems to be only a problem when assigning keys and values by slicing. Any key, value pairs I add on afterwards are just added to the dictionary. Is there some explanation for this?

**EDIT**

Strangely, my own example seems to be working fine in my Shell Terminal, but the actual code it represented is still displacing the first key, value pair. The following is the code I am having trouble with:

```
>>>data = [['even', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'], ['odd', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0',   '1'], ['even', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'x']]
>>> dict1 = {}
>>> dict1[data[0][1]] = data[0][2]
>>> dict1
{'1': '0'}
>>> dict1[data[0][3]] = data[0][4]
>>> dict1
{'1': '1'}
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure you are not initializing `dict1` again?

Comment: Where is the slicing you are talking about?

Comment: I am not initializing dict1 again, all of my code is being done through the Python 3.3 Shell terminal. And @BurhanKhalid, you are correct, I meant indexing, not slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key can only appear once in a given dictionary; if there were two values for a key `k`, it would be ambiguous what `d[k]` was supposed to be. A dictionary is not a list of key-value pairs, no matter how much it might look like one.

When you assign

```
dict1[data[0][3]] = data[0][4]
```

`data[0][3]` is the same as the key `data[0][1]` you assigned a value to earlier. The old value is discarded and replaced by the new one.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. I guess I need to read the documentation a bit closer, hah. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Create `dict_list.py` file , paste following code :

```
data = [['a', 1, 'b', 2], ['c', 3, 'd', 4], ['e', 5, 'f', 7]]
dict1 = {}
dict1[data[0][0]] = data[0][1]
print dict1 # print (dict1) # if python 3.x
dict1[data[0][2]] = data[0][3]
print dict1 # print (dict1) # if python 3.x
```

Run `python dict_list.py`

Output :

```
{'a': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Its as expected .

Answer (score 0):

First of all you made me try it:

```
>>> data = [['a', 1, 'b', 2], ['c', 3, 'd', 4], ['e', 5, 'f', 7]]
>>> 
>>> dic1={}
>>> dic1[data[0][0]] =  data[0][1]
>>> dic1
{'a': 1}
>>> dic1["333"] = 5
>>> dic1
{'a': 1, '333': 5}
>>> dic1[data[0][2]] = data[0][3]
>>> dic1
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, '333': 5}
```

As you can see it works as expected, and I followed your exact actions:

```
>>> dic1 = {}
>>> dic1[data[0][0]] =  data[0][1]
>>> dic1[data[0][2]] = data[0][3]
>>> dic1
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>>
```

On both it works as expected. I guess you executed `dic1 = {}` twice and that is why you saw "a problem". unless there is a somehow bug on your python version, which i guess you don't have. what python version do you have?

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
```

Comment: I typed your code into the Shell Terminal without error. This is very strange, as I have my own nested list, yet I am still receiving the same error as in my OP.
My sys.version information is as follows: 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:18:40) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)].

Comment: @user3239106 So I guess the bug is within the way you use python :)